# gitlabCommitStatus broken: Failed to update Gitlab commit status for project HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am intermittently getting the below error in Jenkins. Nothing has been changed so far.
Jenkins version 2.150.3 and Gitlab plugin version 1.5.11

```
20:31:01  Failed to update Gitlab commit status for project '10750': HTTP 400 Bad Request
```

Errors in jenkins server logs:

```
SEVERE: Failed to update Gitlab commit status for project '10750'
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:197)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.DefaultEntityExtractorFactory$3.extractEntity(DefaultEn
tityExtractorFactory.java:50)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:64)
        at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.$Proxy152.changeBuildStatus(Unknown Source)
        at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.ResteasyGitLabClient.changeBuildStatus(ResteasyGitLabClient.java:60)
        at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient$7.execute(AutodetectingGitLabClient.java:1
12)
        at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient$7.execute(AutodetectingGitLabClient.java:1
09)
        at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient$GitLabOperation.execute(AutodetectingGitLa
bClient.java:335)
        at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient$GitLabOperation.access$100(AutodetectingGi
tLabClient.java:332)
        at com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.gitlab.api.impl.AutodetectingGitLabClient.execute(AutodetectingGitLabClient.java:328
)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Does this happen in jenkins console output during `clone` itself or in some later post-build step where you are trying to programatically make a commit to GitLab?

Comment: @mdabdullah In my case this error happens in a post-build step "Publish build status to GitLab." Note that I am not the author of the question.

Comment: @Mentiflectax please open a new question with screenshots of your  `Git Publisher` section. Generally `HTTP error 400` pertains to client side errors like incorrect username/password, malformed URL etc. and can be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

After investigating this issue I came across this:

[Commit status create (API): Can no longer use links under NAT with 'target_url'](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/66105)

In our organization error occurs since Gitlab Community Edition has been updated to **11.11.8**

```
Status: 400 Bad Request
Response body: {
  "message" : {
    "target_url" : [ "is blocked: Host cannot be resolved or invalid" ]
  }
}
```

@devops What version of Gitlab are you using? Can you provide response body from Jenkins logs?

Comment: I am no longer using GitLab in my current Job. Hence I don't have access to Jenkins logs.

Comment: Sorry @VonC, that question was meant for author of the post. I've edited my comment

Comment: OK, I will delete mine shortly

Answer (score 1):

See if comments of [jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin issue 522](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/522#issuecomment-318032281) could help:

> Just for others who may stumble on this.
>   My issue is that I was trying to describe gitLabBuilds before my main project SCM checkout, and then update them afterwards.
>   This had the weird side-effect of creating GitLab Pipeline jobs for the repo which contains my Jenkinsfile (not the same repo as my main one), and so the attempts to update the status of the wrong repo may well have caused this error.
>
> Took me a minute to relaise gitlabBuilds and gitlabCommitStatus update the last repo checked out, and if the ordering is wrong, it'll try to update the Jenkinsfile repo instead.

---

> I believe this also occurs if you're re-running a build (either resending the hook manually, or rebuilding) to a merge request that has already been merged/closed. Seems like you can't update the status of merged PRs, which makes sense. Possible to add some informational messages for that scenario?

---

> The `BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request` is always thrown when we use a shared library in a pipeline [as explained here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).
>   Obviously Jenkins clones two repositories to build any project: (1) shared library, and (2) project repository.

---

Aslo [`jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin` issue 885](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/885)

> We've seen this error as well.
>   In our case it was due to the Jenkins web hook being registered twice for the Merge Request events in the GitLab project settings.

Answer (score -1):

@VonC
I am having similar issue.
Jenkins ver. `2.176.2` and GitLab plugin `1.5.11`

One day without any config changes but after GitLab update to GitLab Community Edition 11.11.8

I am receiving `Failed to update Gitlab commit status for project '2620': HTTP 400 Bad Request`

My Jennkins file

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'trion/ng-cli-karma'
    }
  }
  options {
    gitLabConnection('https://xxxx.xxxx.xx/')
  }
  triggers {
    gitlab(
      branchFilterType: 'All',
      triggerOnPush: false,
      triggerOnMergeRequest: true,
      triggerOpenMergeRequestOnPush: "source",
      triggerOnAcceptedMergeRequest: true,
      triggerOnClosedMergeRequest: true,
      triggerOnNoteRequest: true,
      noteRegex: "Jenkins please retry a build",
      acceptMergeRequestOnSuccess: true,
      skipWorkInProgressMergeRequest: true,
      ciSkip: false,
      secretToken: "abcd",
      setBuildDescription: true,
      addNoteOnMergeRequest: true,
      addCiMessage: true,
      addVoteOnMergeRequest: true,
      includeBranchesSpec: "",
      excludeBranchesSpec: "",
      pendingBuildName: "",
      sourceBranchRegex: "",
      targetBranchRegex: "")
  }
  stages {
    stage('Check tools') {
      steps {
        gitlabCommitStatus('Check tools') {
          sh 'node -v'
          sh 'npm -v'
          sh 'npm i -g @angular/cli'
          sh 'npm rebuild node-sass --force'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }
    stage('Install modules') {
      steps {
        gitlabCommitStatus('`Install modules`') {
          sh 'npm install'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Run lint') {
      steps {
        gitlabCommitStatus('lint') {
          sh 'npm run lint'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Run tests') {
      steps {
        gitlabCommitStatus('test') {
          sh 'npm run test'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        gitlabCommitStatus('build') {
          sh 'ng build --prod'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to update status with a a get request from Postman/CURL it works just fine ...

Comment: That would be best asked as a separate question: you seem to have used the answer button to ask a question.

Comment: That is not how Stack Overflow works: the button "Answer" is to give an answer to the question which is at the top of the page. If your question is related to this page, ask a new question, with a link back to this one.